# Cross compiling DTC compiler for ARM target

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, buildroot, busybox, device-tree

I need to use DTC on the running ARM target. I've got the sources for the DTC compiler by :
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dtc/dtc.git

Is there any way I can compile the dtc executable statically with cross compiler ?

I need DTC to analyze the device tree structure at runtime by using below command on target:
dtc -I fs /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/

I've nfs mounted RFS. I can keep the dtc executable there to be used on target.

Answer (score 1):

In `buildroot 19.02`. I can see the package `dtc programs` (BR2_PACKAGE_DTC_PROGRAMS)
which install the `dtc` + some other tools (`dtdiff`, `fdtdump`, `fdtget` `fdtput`) on target. It depends on the library `libfdt` (BR2_PACKAGE_DTC), which also needs to be present on the target. (I dont know at which version it was added)

If you just want them in your nfs-mounted rootfs you could still build these packages in `buildroot` and then copy them manually.